# Is there a way to assign a function and create ng-model dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, javascript-databinding

Considering the below code, i am trying to construct `ng-model` dynamically with 2 different objects if it meets the uniqueAttribute condition.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.isUniqueAttribute(entityDefinition)" required />
```

Below is the function where it returns `vm.abc` or `vm.def` to bind to `ng-model`

```
            vm.isUniqueAttribute = function(entityDef) {
                return entityDef.isUnique === 'true' ? 'vm.abc': 'vm.def';
            }
```

But it throws error as:

> Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression
>   'vm.isUniqueAttribute(entityDefinition)' is non-assignable.

Is there a way to handle it like or any alternate way to achieve this?

I can do by assigning it some single object and later classify into 2 different object as a final option. But, just wondering if it can be handled without much effort.

Comment: Your code must work fine. Is `entityDefinition` (which is parameter) defined? The problem is within parameter only.

Comment: not able to assign function to ng-model

Comment: Need to build it using parameter itself. If its true, it shud bind to trueobject or falseobject

Comment: Value of parameter available for that function call or not?

Comment: Yes it has. The data passing from ng-repeat loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use two different elements with two models and with the help of ng-if toggle the required element based on the flag.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.abc" ng-if="vm.isUniqueAttribute(entityDefinition)" required />
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.def" ng-if="!vm.isUniqueAttribute(entityDefinition)"required />
```

Comment: Yup, this can be done. But constraint is this textfields are forming in a loop, so with this approach, we will have 2 input fields always. And if 10, it is double.

Answer (score 0):

You could use bracket notation to set your `ng-model` as a property of an `object` (`vm.modelCollection`) and return the name of the given property with the `isUniqueAttribute` method.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.modelCollection[vm.isUniqueAttribute(entityDefinition)]" required />
```

and then

```
 vm.isUniqueAttribute = function(entityDef) {
     return entityDef.isUnique === 'true' ? 'abc': 'def';
 }
```

I don't know if this approach suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest utilizing a Static Model with Dynamic Content. I have used "ng-init" in my sample to supply the dynamic data, although you can rely on controller to provide it as per your need. (as state here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Sample Code:

```
$scope.Model = [];
$scope.SetModelWithDynamicContent = function(index) {
if ($scope.Model.indexOf(index) == -1) {
  //Add your conidition here(.isunique). I have used odd or even number.
  if (index % 2 == 0)
    $scope.Model.push({
      Property: "Bind vm.abc"
    });
  else
    $scope.Model.push({
      Property: "Bind vm.def"
    });
}
```

The complete code for it can be found at http://plnkr.co/edit/gFa26r?p=preview

Please remember to mark this as answer if it solves your problem!